# How can I view all the jslint errors in IntelliJ?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jslint

IntelliJ underline in red every error reported by JSLint and I can see the respective indications on the rightmost margin of the document.

However, I would like to see all of the jslint errors in one window and be able to navigate from error to error.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: in visual studio you can set the options for JSLint to mark output as errors, which will give you navigatable list of all the errors; there may be a similar setting for JSLint under IntelliJ.

Comment: I certainly hope so. The question is where?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run `Analyze` | **Inspect Code** with the **JSLint** code inspection enabled in the profile.